# Using @OneToOne with @Where

Tags: scala, hibernate, jpa

Let's assume that I have 2 entites: `Body` and `Leg`. `Leg` has field `side` (it's value can be either `Left` or `Right`) and also has foreign key to `Body`.

I'm sure that every instance of `Body` has only one left and only one right leg. So I want to create 2 `One-To-One` mappings between `Body` and `Leg` based on value of `side` field.

In other words, I have `One-To-Many` relation on database level, and want to get `One-To-One` in the model. Is it possible?

***Body.scala***

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "body")
case class Body(
    @(Id@field)
    var id: String = null,

    @(OneToOne@field)(cascade = Array(CascadeType.ALL), mappedBy = "body")
    var leftLeg: Leg = null,

    @(OneToOne@field)(cascade = Array(CascadeType.ALL), mappedBy = "body")
    var rightLeg: Leg = null
)
```

***Leg.scala***

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "leg")
case class Leg(
    @(Id@field)
    var id: String = null,

    @(OneToOne@field)
    @(JoinColumn@field)(name = "body_id")
    var body: Body = null,

    @(Column@field)
    var side: String = null
)
```

Of course, I can do it as `One-To-Many` and add 2 getters for each leg, but I also need to filter by left leg (for example) in reporsitory, so want to write something like this

```
@Query(value = "select b from Body b where b.id = ?1 and b.leftLeg.size = ?2)
def findBodyByLegSize(bodyId: String, size: String): Body
```

Answer (score 0):

the Only solution is to duplicate Leg Class to **LeftLeg** and **RightLeg** and create two tables of Leg (you can use extends)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LeftLeg")
case class LeftLeg (
    @(Id@field)
    var id: String = null,

    @(OneToOne@field)
    @(JoinColumn@field)(name = "body_id")
    var body: Body = null,

    @(Column@field)
    var side: String = null
)
```